# How to integrate IMDB API with CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter-3, imdb

I have tried a lot but can't find any reasonable source to integrate imdb api in my CodeIgniter App to fetch movies info from IMDB and getting store in my database.

Comment: As it stands this question is far too broad, arguably for any Q&A platform on the web. It is much better for you to show us the code you have tried so readers can help you with whatever problems you are having. I expect you will need the Curl PHP module, or a library that wraps it, such as [Pest](https://github.com/educoder/pest) or [Guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org). Pest is the easier of the two to use, and Guzzle is more flexible and well-maintained. They both have example code, and there should be some docs available on IMDB itself as well.